# SQL Query for poorly designed database

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table with data in it like the following:

```html
TableID Vendor ID DETAILS
1     SYS         *Hamburger Rolls <*Hamburger Rolls>
2     SYS         *WHEAT <WHEAT>
3     SYS         *2.99 <2.99>
4     SYS         *1364 <1364>
5     SYS         *WHITE <WHITE>
6     SYS         *1.99 <1.99>
7     SYS         *1363<1363>
8     SYS         *Hotdog Rolls <*HotDog Rolls>
9     SYS         *WHEAT <WHEAT>
10     SYS         *WHITE <WHITE>
11     SYS         *1.49 <1.49>
```

I need to find a way too query this data into a better formatted results list or possibly an XML file. Notice that the data in the `Details` column goes in order where everything below the item name is associated with the item. Id like a result set along the lines of:

```html
VendorID Item             ItemType Price ItemID
SYS         Hambergurer Rolls Wheat     2.99 1364
SYS         Hambergurer Rolls White     1.99 1363
SYS         HotDog Rolls     Wheat  
SYS         HotDog Rolls     White     1.49
```

or

```html
<SYS>
     <Hamburger Rolls>
            <Wheat>
          <Price>2.99</Price>
                 <ItemID>1364</ItemID>
             </Wheat>
             <White>
                 <Price>1.99</Price>
                 <ItemID>1363</ItemID>
             <White>
     </Hamburger Rolls>
```

But I'm having a hard time generating a query either way that will format the data the way I need it. Please help!

Comment: Is there any chance to get the quality of a row? First it looks like Product, followed by three-liners consisting of "made of", price and itemid. But the you have the Hotdog Rolls, where this information is incomplete...

Comment: But how do you know which of the rows is really an item name?  And how can you tell by looking at a line whether it is a new row or an attribute on an old row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I took the leading "*" in the XML-kind extension as mark of a new product, the quality of being numeric with a "." as price, being numeric without a "." seems to be the ItemID and what remains is the ItemType... As the title says: **very** poorly formatted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I place this in another answer to keep both approaches clean:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TableID INT,Vendor_ID VARCHAR(10),DETAILS VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'SYS','*Hamburger Rolls <*Hamburger Rolls>')
,(2,'SYS','*WHEAT <WHEAT>')
,(3,'SYS','*2.99 <2.99>')
,(4,'SYS','*1364 <1364>')
,(5,'SYS','*WHITE <WHITE>')
,(6,'SYS','*1.99 <1.99>')
,(7,'SYS','*1363<1363>')
,(8,'SYS','*Hotdog Rolls <*HotDog Rolls>')
,(9,'SYS','*WHEAT <WHEAT>')
,(10,'SYS','*WHITE <WHITE>')
,(11,'SYS','*1.49 <1.49>');

WITH CleanedData AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.TableID) RowInx
          ,tbl.TableID
          ,tbl.Vendor_ID
          ,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(tbl.DETAILS,2,CHARINDEX('<',tbl.DETAILS)-2)) AS DetailsClean
          ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(InnerInfo.Data,1,1)='*' THEN 'Product'
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(InnerInfo.Data)=1 AND CHARINDEX('.',InnerInfo.Data)>0 THEN 'Price'
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(InnerInfo.Data)=1 THEN 'ItemID'
                ELSE 'MadeOf' END AS LineType  
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tbl.DETAILS,CHARINDEX('<',tbl.DETAILS),1000),'<',''),'>','')
    ) AS InnerInfo(Data)
)
,DistinctVendors AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Vendor_ID 
    FROM CleanedData 
)
SELECT dv.Vendor_ID 
      ,Product.DetailsClean AS Item
      ,MadeOf.DetailsClean AS ItemType
      ,Price.DetailsClean AS Price
      ,ItemID.DetailsClean AS ItemID
FROM DistinctVendors AS dv
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT cd1.* 
    FROM CleanedData AS cd1 
    WHERE cd1.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
    AND cd1.LineType='Product'
) AS Product
OUTER APPLY
(

    SELECT cd2.*

    FROM CleanedData AS cd2
    WHERE cd2.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
    AND cd2.RowInx BETWEEN Product.RowInx+1 AND ISNULL(
                                            (SELECT TOP 1 x.RowInx 
                                                FROM CleanedData AS x 
                                                WHERE x.LineType='Product' 
                                                AND  x.RowInx>Product.RowInx 
                                                ORDER BY x.RowInx DESC)-1,100000)
    AND cd2.LineType='MadeOf'
) AS MadeOf
OUTER APPLY
(

    SELECT cd3.*
    FROM CleanedData AS cd3
    WHERE cd3.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
    AND cd3.RowInx BETWEEN MadeOf.RowInx+1 AND MadeOf.RowInx+3
    AND cd3.LineType='Price'
) AS Price
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT cd3.*
    FROM CleanedData AS cd3
    WHERE cd3.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
    AND cd3.RowInx BETWEEN MadeOf.RowInx+1 AND MadeOf.RowInx+3
    AND cd3.LineType='ItemID'
) AS ItemID
```

The result

```
Vendor_ID     Item              ItemType    Price   ItemID
SYS           Hamburger Rolls   WHEAT       2.99    1364
SYS           Hamburger Rolls   WHITE       1.99    1363
SYS           Hotdog Rolls      WHEAT       1.49    NULL
SYS           Hotdog Rolls      WHITE       1.49    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks I have not tried it yet but I believe this will accomplish what I need.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TableID INT,Vendor_ID VARCHAR(10),DETAILS VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'SYS','*Hamburger Rolls <*Hamburger Rolls>')
,(2,'SYS','*WHEAT <WHEAT>')
,(3,'SYS','*2.99 <2.99>')
,(4,'SYS','*1364 <1364>')
,(5,'SYS','*WHITE <WHITE>')
,(6,'SYS','*1.99 <1.99>')
,(7,'SYS','*1363<1363>')
,(8,'SYS','*Hotdog Rolls <*HotDog Rolls>')
,(9,'SYS','*WHEAT <WHEAT>')
,(10,'SYS','*WHITE <WHITE>')
,(11,'SYS','*1.49 <1.49>');

WITH CleanedData AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.TableID) RowInx
          ,tbl.TableID
          ,tbl.Vendor_ID
          ,RTRIM(SUBSTRING(tbl.DETAILS,2,CHARINDEX('<',tbl.DETAILS)-2)) AS DetailsClean
          ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(InnerInfo.Data,1,1)='*' THEN 'Product'
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(InnerInfo.Data)=1 AND CHARINDEX('.',InnerInfo.Data)>0 THEN 'Price'
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(InnerInfo.Data)=1 THEN 'ItemID'
                ELSE 'MadeOf' END AS LineType  
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tbl.DETAILS,CHARINDEX('<',tbl.DETAILS),1000),'<',''),'>','')
    ) AS InnerInfo(Data)
)
,DistinctVendors AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Vendor_ID 
    FROM CleanedData 
)
SELECT dv.Vendor_ID AS [@Vendor_ID]
      ,(
         SELECT cd1.DetailsClean AS [@Product]
               ,(
                  SELECT cd2.DetailsClean AS [@MadeOf]
                               ,(
                                  SELECT cd3.DetailsClean AS [@Price]
                                  FROM CleanedData AS cd3
                                  WHERE cd3.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
                                    AND cd3.RowInx BETWEEN cd2.RowInx+1 AND cd2.RowInx+3
                                    AND cd3.LineType='Price'
                                  FOR XML PATH('Price'),TYPE
                                )
                               ,(
                                  SELECT cd3.DetailsClean AS [@ItemID]
                                  FROM CleanedData AS cd3
                                  WHERE cd3.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
                                    AND cd3.RowInx BETWEEN cd2.RowInx+1 AND cd2.RowInx+3
                                    AND cd3.LineType='ItemID'
                                  FOR XML PATH('ItemID'),TYPE
                                )
                  FROM CleanedData AS cd2
                  WHERE cd2.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
                    AND cd2.RowInx BETWEEN cd1.RowInx+1 AND ISNULL(
                                                            (SELECT TOP 1 x.RowInx 
                                                             FROM CleanedData AS x 
                                                             WHERE x.LineType='Product' 
                                                              AND  x.RowInx>cd1.RowInx 
                                                             ORDER BY x.RowInx DESC)-1,100000)
                    AND cd2.LineType='MadeOf'
                  FOR XML PATH('MadeOf'),TYPE
                )
         FROM CleanedData AS cd1 
         WHERE cd1.Vendor_ID=dv.Vendor_ID
           AND cd1.LineType='Product'
         FOR XML PATH('Product'),TYPE
       )
FROM DistinctVendors AS dv
FOR XML PATH('Vendor'),ROOT('root')
```

The result:

```
<root>
  <Vendor Vendor_ID="SYS">
    <Product Product="Hamburger Rolls">
      <MadeOf MadeOf="WHEAT">
        <Price Price="2.99" />
        <ItemID ItemID="1364" />
      </MadeOf>
      <MadeOf MadeOf="WHITE">
        <Price Price="1.99" />
        <ItemID ItemID="1363" />
      </MadeOf>
    </Product>
    <Product Product="Hotdog Rolls">
      <MadeOf MadeOf="WHEAT">
        <Price Price="1.49" />
      </MadeOf>
      <MadeOf MadeOf="WHITE">
        <Price Price="1.49" />
      </MadeOf>
    </Product>
  </Vendor>
</root>
```